# Invoke OS command in R - best practice

Tags: r, command-line, operating-system

I was wondering what the best way to invoke an OS command in R is, since there are so many options:

```
system(...)
system2(...)
shell(...)
```

and just recently I stumpled upon

```
eval(call(...)
```

Is there a best practice on what function to use for each OS? Are there limitations to any of these invokation functions? Any clarification would be helpful.

Comment: `eval(call(...))` doesn't belong to this group, since it is meant to prepare calls to `R` (and not system) functions. The doc gives hints on which function to use depending on the OS. However, I don't think it's right to use those functions; very often a plain `R` alternative is available. Using those functions you may lose the usual portability of `R` code.

Comment: In short, usually you want to use `system` on a UNIX-like OS and `shell` on Windows. See some example usage at https://github.com/Rapporter/pander/blob/master/R/convert.R#L7

Comment: @nicola , I have seen functions were 'eval(call())' was used to invoke a system call. This made me wonder, why anyone would use/prefer it over the the existing options. 
If you for example work in the field of remote sensing were you analyze large data amounts (satellite imagery), you sometimes have to run certain algorithms in python or c  (GDAL, OTB,...) because they are way too slow in R.  That's when you need the command line interface of R that gives you the flexibility to use all the tools you need in order to make your program efficent and fast as possible.

Comment: Again, `eval(call())` evaluates an `R` expression; of course if the expression calls `system` (or similar) a system call is made, but that's not a feature of `eval(call())` by itself. Since it happens that you don't have problems of portability and are using specific tools, I'd just go with whatever works. Don't forget that some libraries (like GDAL) are already wrapped in `R`; the package `rgdal` can give access natively in R, without any system call.